# Dense and countable subset example of $\mathbb{R}$ without using $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there an example of a countable and dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (or $[0,1]$) without its construction strictly relying on $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

I thought about the dyadic rational numbers, but they are already represented as fractions, e.g. $\frac{m}{2^n}$.
It would be better to have a construction relying only on a set construction process without relying (explictly) on $\mathbb{Q}$ (as in the Cantor ternary set, as we take the limit of a set construction process).

Comment: The set of algebraic real numbers?

Comment: @GEdgar I like it, but one could argue that algebraic real numbers are built off of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and thus might not fit the spirit

Comment: @Alan: the algebraic real numbers can be defined just using $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want this?

Comment: @RobArthan A question some students had in a measure theory course.

Comment: $\{a+b\pi:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Let us divide $[0,1]$ into two intervals of equal length. Let us choose **any** element from the first and second interval. Then divide the intervals and repeat the process, choosing numbers different from already chosen. Repeat etc.

Comment: Nice answer.   Bonus points for a construction that doesn't involve the Axiom of Countable Choice :)

Comment: Nice answer for $[0,1]$. @Alan However you would need the axiom of countable choice for this to work with $\mathbb{R}$, writing for example $$\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[n,n+1)$$ Am I correct ?

Comment: Przemyslaw's answer does indeed use countable choice. I assume Alan was asking for one that doesn't.  Only a small variation is needed. Just start with $0$, $1$, and an irrational in-between.. Add the mid-points of the two intervals formed. Then add the mid-points of the four intervals formed, and so on. The set constructed is countable and dense in $[0,1]$

Comment: @DavidHartley: There is absolutely no need to use the axiom of choice in this case. Yes, formally speaking we rely on choice in the formulated proof, but it's a bit nitpicky to say that this relies on choice.

Comment: @Flewer47: Where would choice come in there, though?

Comment: @Alan: While, as I said, you're not really relying on choice here (since we can always choose midpoints, or whatever). If anything, however, you'd need Dependent Choice, which is strictly stronger than countable choice, since each stage depends on what choices we made in prior steps.

Answer (score 1):

It is well know (probably showed by Cantor) that every two countable dense linear orders without endpoints are isomorphic. In particular, every countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Edit:** For a specific example, take your favorite countable and not bounded $D_0 \subset \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \mathbb{Q}$, and defined a family $\{D_i: i \in \omega\}$ as follow:

$D_{i+1} \subset \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \mathbb{Q}$ is the $\subset$-minimum such as for any $a, b \in D_i$ with $a<b$ there are $x, y, z \in D_{i+1}$ with $x<a<y<b<z$.

You can check that each $D_i$ is countable and $D=\bigcup_{i \in \omega}D_i$ is countable dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: This is true, however I am asking for a specific example, not a general result.

Comment: I edited my aswer, there are many examples but all of those are isomorphic.